# Get how many times an array appears in a List<>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm developing a section with some statistics for my website and I'm having some troubles to figure out how to get "popular things" (explanation below):

I have the following table:

```
ID | Spell1ID | Spell2ID
1 | 4 | 12
2 | 4 | 12
3 | 12 | 4
4 | 1 | 8
5 | 3 | 12
6 | 8 | 1
```

In order to get that data I'm doing the following:

```
List<short[]> spellsList = new List<short[]>();

..

            using (MySqlDataReader dbReader = Conex.Command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dbReader.Read())
                {
                    short[] tempArray = new short[2];

                    tempArray[0] = dbReader.GetInt16("spell1ID");
                    tempArray[1] = dbReader.GetInt16("spell2ID");

                    spellsList.Add(tempArray);
                }
            }
```

Now, I need to calculate which of those values are the most common ones (descending from most common to less common) and the order of the values of each array in the list shouldn't be important ([4,12] and [12,4] are the same because what I actually need is the SpellID and how frequent its used), so for this example this would be:

```
1- 4, 12 (3 times)
2- 1,8 (2 times)
3- 3,12
```

It would be great if this can be done using LINQ pref with lambda expressions.

Sorry if this is confusing, english is not my first language.

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow is for helping you write your own code, not for having other people write your code for you. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried. That said, from your description so far (which isn't very clear to me), it seems you should sort `tempArray` and then use [`GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334(v=vs.110).aspx) with an `IEqualityComparer` to handle comparing the arrays. The count of each resulting group will tell you the number of times each combination appears.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I agree 100% on StackOverflow helping to write my own code and sorry if my question wasn't clear. I didn't tried anything in particular because I was stucked in the logic itself. Now, with Mangist's answer I realize how I should've used LINQ to solve my problem. Appreciate your comment and your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var spellsList = new List<short[]>();

        spellsList.Add(new short[] {4, 12 });
        spellsList.Add(new short[] {4, 12 });
        spellsList.Add(new short[] {12, 4 });
        spellsList.Add(new short[] { 1, 8});
        spellsList.Add(new short[] {3, 12});
        spellsList.Add(new short[] {8, 1 });
        spellsList.Add(new short[] {8, 1 });
        spellsList.Add(new short[] {8, 1 });
        spellsList.Add(new short[] {8, 1 });


        var result = spellsList.Select(s => s[0] > s[1] ? String.Format("{0},{1}", s[0], s[1]) : String.Format("{0},{1}", s[1], s[0]))
                               .GroupBy(s => s)
                               .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
                               .ToList();

        result.ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine($"{g.Key}: {g.Count()} times"));

        Console.Read();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Mangist for your answer, it worked. Now I know that I have to study LINQ deeper to understand in the future how to solve problems like this. Very grateful for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
// fake data
var data = @"1 | 4 | 12
            2 | 4 | 12
            3 | 12 | 4
            4 | 1 | 8
            5 | 3 | 12
            6 | 8 | 1"
.Split('\n')
.Select(x => x.Split(new[] { " | " }, StringSplitOptions.None));

var spellsList = data.Select(x => new[]
{
    int.Parse(x[1]), int.Parse(x[2])
});

// query
var combos = spellsList
    .GroupBy(spells => string.Join(", ", spells.OrderBy(x => x)), (k, g) => new
    {
        SpellCombo = k,
        CastCount = g.Count(),
    })
    .OrderBy(x => x.CastCount)
    .ToList();

foreach(var combo in combos)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Combo {combo.SpellCombo} is casted {combo.CastCount} times. ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Xiaoy312 for your answer, you gave me another approach to solve future problems like this. Thanks you very much!